# Is there a way to "compress" a model in blender without losing quality?

Tags: blender

It is possible to compress an mp3 track without loosing perceivable quality. My question is : Is there a way, once the model is done, to reduce the complexity of that model without loosing quality, so as to make rendering easier one's computer ?

Answer (score 0):

It is common to make a high poly model and then [retopologise](https://conceptartempire.com/retopology/) it to get a low poly mesh that is easier to animate, or better suited for use in a game engine.

A common workflow is

- sculpt a high poly mesh to the desired shape.
- Then model a new mesh and use [surface snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) to keep the new mesh stuck to the detailed surface. There are also addons that can help, like [CGCookies retopoFlow](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow) or [Quad remesher](https://www.blendernation.com/2019/10/18/quad-remesher-auto-retopologizer-for-blender-unofficial-faq/).
- You can then bake a normal map that can make the low poly mesh visually the same as the high poly mesh.

Comment: There's also the Decimate modifier, which can make an automated attempt (quite likely to screw up, but it will reduce vertex count as ordered). Complex geometry limits animation far more than rendering itself, though; if the goal is to make rendering easier, it might be meaningful to look at shaders and rendering parameters.

Comment: @YannVernier, yes the decimate modifier can reduce the poly count, in 2.81 which is to be released soon, there is also voxel remesh and quadriflow remesh that preserve the shape better than decimate. Manual retopo is still the most common method, I just wanted to mention some tools available. While shaders require some calculations, the steps to find the visible geometry and what adds to light and reflection at each point is much greater than the shader calculations, this makes reducing geometry of greater benefit. Rendering paramaters are specific to which unmentioned renderer is used.